# Visual Studio 2017 unit test fails with error Could not locate debug symbols for 'C:\git\96522204\DS97981\A6\A6\bin\Debug\A6.exe'

Tags: visual-studio

I have been trying to run a code in VS 2017, and the build succeeds, but the unit tests fail with the error:

Could not locate debug symbols for 'C:\git\96522204\DS97981\A6\A6\bin\Debug\A6.exe'. To make use of '--list_content' discovery, ensure that debug symbols are available or make use of '' via a .runsettings file.

in the output. what is the problem?

Comment: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/178469/tests-could-not-locate-debug-symbols.html

Comment: @HansPassant: thanks for providing the link. I can see the mentioned solution that the file .runsettings is being added with some xml contents. Do you know the path to add this file ?

Comment: @HansPassant: it also mentioned in your's provided link that "issue belongs to the boost adapter". but I am not sure someone have reported the issue to Microsoft git hub (in given link) and what is the genuine solution?